# How to smooth changes in *current* in a current meter?

Tags: passive-networks, passive-filter, passive-components

I have a milliammeter I'd like to debounce with an \$f_c\$ of say 0.1 Hz (10 s) to where it reads a mean average rather than however fast the needle moves, dampened only by physics. Vcc is about 8-9 V dc, and the load circuit under test series equivalent resistance varies from 50 to 330 Ω.

Comment: You have an old-school moving-coil milli-ammeter? It should have a fixed internal resistance that you might be able to damp with a parallel capacitor. Simple RC time constant.

Comment: The current through the ammeter is the same as the current through the load. Therefore you cannot filter the current in the ammeter without filtering the current in the load (in other words, changing that which you are trying to measure). Also, do to the way the universe is constructed, any changes to load current imposed by you will manifest as changes in voltage to the load.

Comment: The best thing to do is to run your current through a shunt resistor, and measure the voltage across the shunt. You can filter the shunt voltage between shunt and voltmeter.

Comment: @glen_geek Yes. I'll have to put on an RLC meter to figure it out. Can you make an answer rather than a comment? Thanks.

Comment: @mkeith That's how to measure current across a sense resistor with a voltmeter, not an ammeter. Thanks but I already have a solution.

Comment: First order passive is gonna be a no-go in the real world. Giant cap or inductor not gonna verk with actual magic smoke pixies.

Comment: Studying the accepted solution, I see that it is to put the load through a shunt. And put a capacitor across the shunt. Which is exactly what I said. Not everybody watches AvE. You may find that your questions and comment will be more clearly understood if you use plain old english. You can increase the order of the filter if you like by adding more series R and shunt C. Just have to account for the effect of the series R on the DC reading.

Comment: @glen Whatever, I only speak curmudgeon and binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A D'Arsonval mechanical meter movement already employs damping. If well-designed, the needle will come to rest with no overshoot. Settling time is in the 0.2 second ballpark.

It is difficult to speed response without reducing sensitivity, but slowing response to be **over-damped** is possible with a parallel capacitor. Over-damping should be possible with a series inductor too, but this would be very large and bulky.

For your case, 9V into a 50 ohm load would generate a current of 0.18A. If your meter has switched-scales, you'd perhaps use the next highest scale. If you have a raw meter movement, you'd use a *shunt resistor* in parallel with the meter movement whose value brings 0.18A to full-scale swing. An over-damping capacitor would be parallel with all:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiApZf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This example takes a 50 uA meter movement whose internal winding resistance is 3k, adds a 0.833333 ohm shunt to make a current meter that goes full-scale at 0.18 A. A damping capacitor in parallel with the shunt would have to be an enormous 120,000 uF to achieve a 0.1 second time constant. This would likely have to be a super-capacitor needing a very low voltage rating (since the meter's burden voltage is a fraction of a volt).

Comment: Thar she chooches. Basically turn it into a ye olden 80's fuel gauge that moves ever so slowly. Differential equation fu 

Comment: @Barry Sorta recall slow analog fuel gauges. I'd have guessed that they were *so very slow* that they'd have used a thermal response of some type.

Comment: If I reckon incorrectly, it was usually a float connected to a linear potentiometer debounced so that sloshing fuel readings not debounced by the mechanical float system (which acts like a pendulum) wouldn't move around with a near the float's natural harmonics. This meant staying too long uphill or downhill would eventually result in wrong readings, which likely happens these days as well. Maybe some fancy piezoelectric mounts coupled with a 3-axis accelerometer would be able to measure fuel more precisely. Kinda moot considering ICE is a DOA. 

Comment: @Barry You've suggested another damping solution for your posted question: enclose your meter movement in an oil bath. That could be as slow as molasses in January.

Comment: Ah the ol' air pressure gauge-style. That would work too but I'm not gonna risk releasing the shmoo all over the kitchen table. Mucho creative hackination appreciated! Definitely folks can use thickness-specific nonconductive fluids to dampen their gauges.

Answer (score 1):

1st order passive filter for a electro-mechanical mA meter.

To create a dampened response @ 0.1Hz  means the rise time is about Tr=0.35/f= 3.5 seconds.

If the meter shunt resistor is approx.  or < 1 Ohm and the minimum load is 50 Ω then the C across the meter must be RC=T or C > 3.5s/50Ω = 70 mF.  This is a p[olarized part](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/electric-double-layer-capacitors-edlc-supercapacitors/61?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv7=3&sf=0&FV=ffe0003d&quantity=&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25) but may be rated or low voltage across the meter. < 1V.